# Order Number which dosnt exists in other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a question. How can I write this SQL

**First Table**

1. Name: ORDER_TABLE
2. Column: Order_number, Contract_number,vendor_number

**Second Table**

1. Name: CONTRACT_TABLE
2. Column: Contract_number, vendor_number

I have a one contract_number ='1234' which contain in CONTRACT_TABLE but I want check does this contract_number have a order. I want get score this Contract_number which doesnt have Order_number in ORDER_TABLE

```
SELECT ct.VENDOR_NUMBER, ct.CONTRACT_NUMBER, ot.ORDER_NUMBER
FROM CONTRACT_TABLE ct,
     ORDER_TABLE ot
WHERE ct.vendor_number = ot.vendor_number
```

Comment: so you have the SQL, huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to detect all the Contract_number in  CONTRACT_TABLE which does not exits in  ORDER_TABLE (not clear from your description) here is one exemple ofsql:

```
select Contract_number from CONTRACT_TABLE
minus select distinct Contract_number from ORDER_TABLE
```

Comment: no worries. Just make sure Contract_number is either a primary key or an indexed column on either tables to avoid any performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    Contract_Number
FROM
    Contract_Table
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT
         NULL
    FROM
         Order_Table
    WHERE
         Contract_Table.Order_Number = Order_Table.Order_Number)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT ct.VENDOR_NUMBER, ct.CONTRACT_NUMBER, ot.ORDER_NUMBER
FROM CONTRACT_TABLE ct
     LEFT JOIN ORDER_TABLE ot
        ON ct.vendor_number = ot.vendor_number
```

Then if there is no corresponding record in `ORDER_TABLE`, you will still get the contract details but the `ORDER_NUMBER` column will return `NULL`.

If you only want to return contracts where there is no order then you can add a where clause to filter:

```
WHERE ot.ORDER_NUMBER IS NULL
```

This is one of the reasons why it is a good idea to switch to the newer ANSI 92 JOIN syntax instead of the older ANSI 89 implicit join syntax you are using. [This article](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), although mostly about SQL-Server does list some good reasons to switch to the newer style join syntax.

*Note - There are some rare cases where Oracle will optimize an implicit join better than an explicit join, but these are the exception to the rule, almost all the time the two methods will generate the same plan*

Comment: Btw: Oracle recommends in the manual to use explicit `JOIN`s especially for outer joins (and stop using the  `(+)` operator)

Comment: A link to the part in the manual @a_horse_with_no_name is referring to is here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm#sthref2257

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ORDER_TABLE
TABLE ( ORDER_NUMBER INT, CONTRACT_NUMBER INT ,VENDOR_NUMBER INT)

DECLARE @CONTRACT_TABLE TABLE
(CONTRACT_NUMBER INT , VENDOR_NUMBER INT)


SELECT 
    C.CONTRACT_NUMBER , 
    COUNT(ORDER_NUMBER)  AS ORDER_SCORE
FROM 
    @ORDER_TABLE O
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    @CONTRACT_TABLE C ON C.CONTRACT_NUMBER = O.CONTRACT_NUMBER
GROUP BY C.CONTRACT_NUMBER
HAVING COUNT(O.ORDER_NUMBER)= 0
```

Comment: That is not valid SQL for Oracle

Comment: * THIS IS FOR MSSQL SERVER. THANK YOU.

Comment: Correct (and SQL Server **only**). So why did you post that to a question related to Oracle?

Comment: it is nothing but a solution u can drive it on oracle environment. I just wanna paste logic nothing else MR. a_horse_with_no_name.